# RLE algorithm decoding - escape character

Tags: c

I have to do a rle algorithm (escape character) that is able to encode and decode every file. 
I did the first part (encoding) and now already before to begin the decoding part i can see some problems. Example:

If I have a file and inside it there is: `AAAAABBBBBBCCCCCDDD`
The encode function that I did give an output like this: `QA5QB6QC5DDD`

But you have to think that I have to work with real file so inside there is not just letter also numbers and symbols.

So, after the encode part, what I have to do if inside the encoded file there is something like `QA55`?
The output have to be `AAAAA5` or fifty five `A`?

Another example, if I have to read `QA5`
Which is the final output? `AAAAA` or just `QA5`?

I mean that I don't know how I can recognize when the block of letter that I'm reading is something of encoded or not.

This is my encode function:

```
void encode (FILE *source, FILE *destination) {
    char currentChar;
    char seqChar = 'Z'; //could be any character
    int count = 0;

    while(1) {
      int endFile = (fread(&currentChar, sizeof(char),1, source) == 0); 

      if(endFile || seqChar!=currentChar) {

         if(count>3) {
           char escape = 'Q';
           int k = count; 
           char str[100];
           int digits = sprintf(str,"%d",count); 
           fwrite(&escape, sizeof(escape), 1, destination);
           fwrite(&seqChar, sizeof(escape),1, destination);
           fwrite(&str, sizeof(char), digits, destination);
         }
         else {
           for(int i=0;i<count;i++) 
              fwrite(&seqChar,sizeof(char),1,destination);
         }
         seqChar = currentChar;
         count =1;
      }

     else count++;

     if(endFile)
       break;
    }

   fclose(source);
   fclose(destination);
}
```

I hope you know what I mean,
for sure, I think, that I have to invent some convention in order to solve this problem, but I can not figure out which and what kind.

Comment: What if you just got rid of the escape hatch?  Basically, instead of returning `QA5QB6QC5DDD`, give `QA5QB6QC5QD3`.  Then it's unambiguous (at the risk of expanding your file instead of compressing it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you place a literal backslash in a C string? How do you write a percent sign with printf? You have to find an escape sequence that represents the escape character itself.

Your escape character is **Q** (strange choice, by the way). Then **Q** + *character* + *count* could mean: that *character*, *count* times. And **QQ** could mean the escape character itself.

You'll see that you cannot compress sequences of **Q**'s that way, because **Q** already means "Q". There are two possibilities to fix this: Get rid of the **QQ** special meaning and always encode "Q" as a sequence of one "Q", ie. **QQ1**. Or place the count in front of the character to encode and have **Q** not be a valid count.

(By the way, that's not so much a C question, it's more about the design of your compression algorithm. You might want to re-tag it and remove the code.)